# Magento 2 error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: magento2, error, redirect, magento-2.1.1

On a new install of Magento CE 2.1.3 I am getting this ***ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*** error once the page loads both in frontend and backend.

After browser cache is cleared page will load once or twice the error listed in Title happens along with the "*try clearing your cookies*" message.

I've looked at the `.htaccess` file and `core_config_data` table in the DB both look like the defaults. The browsers used are Chrome and FireFox.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: check log files

Comment: Which log files?! I checked the Installation log files and they gave a PHP deprecated error - generic in nature. Maybe I should reinstall?!

Answer (score -1):

Issue resolved. It was a hosting provider server setup issue. Thanks for the responses.